# How can I add 2 views to a UICollectionViewCell with different zPositions relative to a view outside the collection view?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uikit, uicollectionviewcell

So, I want to accomplish the following, so that I can show view A in between 2 views of cells of a collection view:

Hierarchy:

```
- View A (layer.zPosition: 0)
- Collection view (layer.zPosition: 0)
    - Collection View Cell (layer.zPosition: 0)
        - View B (layer.zPosition: 1)
        - View C (layer.zPosition: -1)
```

However, this does not work, as in it shows both the view b and c on top of view a. Any suggestions?